# Looping in Eloquent Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, syntax, for-loop

I cam across the following function in javascript:

```
for (var number = 0; number <= 12; number = number + 2)
  show(number);
```

The Output is the following

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
```

I expected it to be

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
```

Why is the "0" shown first and not "2" since the "number = number + 2"comes before the "show(number);"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This because the order of the loop is like this:

1. Init number.
2. Check the condition.
3. Run the loop.
4. Increase number by 2.

and then 2-4 again until the condition is false, if so exits the loop.

the **for** loop translate to something like this:

```
var number = 0;
while (number <= 12)
{
  show(number);
  number = number + 2;
}
```

In general for loop **always** work like this:

```
for(Init Variable; Condition ; Changing Variable)
{
   //Some Code
}
```

translates to:

```
Init Variable
while (Condition )
{
  //Some Code

  Changing Variable
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply.

Comment: I expected it to translate to

    var number = 0;
    while (number <= 12)
    {
      number = number + 2;
      show(number);
    }



not 

    var number = 0;
    while (number <= 12)
    {
      show(number);
      number = number + 2;
    }


So I guess the for-loop just works a little different than the while-loop as discribed by you, right?

Comment: Sorry, got the formatting wrong:

@Dor Cohen

@Dor Cohen

I expected it to translate to


`var number = 0;
while (number <= 12)
{
  number = number + 2;
  show(number);
}`




not 

`var number = 0;
while (number <= 12)
{
  show(number);
  number = number + 2;
}`



So I guess the for-loop just works a little different than the while-loop as discribed by you, right?

Comment: I didn't understand you, the for-loop works exactly as the while loop I described..

Comment: If I put the "show(number)" in the while-loop at the very end (after the "number = number + 2") the result will be 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 as I have expected in the first place (at least int the eloquent-javascript console). In the while-loop you have to put the "show(number)" before the "number = number + 2" in order to get 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12. In the for-loop you can put the "show(number)" at the end and still get "0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12.

Answer (score 2):

think of it like this :

why did you write the yellow part ? [image]

this is the seed part which you DO WANT TO BE CONSIDERED !

so it will start with its seed value and then  - will be incremented ....

Answer (score 1):

0 is the initial value for the number variable in the for loop of the function:

```
var number = 0;
```

The for loop is terminated when the number variable reaches 12:

```
number <= 12;
```

Here is some more information on for loops: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp